# Google API PHP client trouble

Tags: php, google-api, digital-ocean

I have tried everything, but can't seem to simply get it to work.

I was using these scripts happily on a bluehost hosting, till I decided to move to digital ocean.

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/1.1.4

https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/tree/2.3.5

I built a custom function to read spreadsheets and use it as a database for a client who needed the ability to edit the website texts himself.

I took a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14.04 server, installed Sentora Panel on it, normal PHP code works, but specifically this Google API script is throwing this error.

```
[Fri Jul 29 05:21:24.569294 2016] [:error] [pid 2429] [client 14.139.122.50:53019] PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/Google_Client/5f/5fa67135f8773ebac807e4dda0aa1084) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in:/var/sentora/temp/) in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Cache/File.php on line 52
[Fri Jul 29 05:21:25.985927 2016] [:error] [pid 2429] [client 14.139.122.50:53019] PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/Google_Client/5f) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in:/var/sentora/temp/) in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Cache/File.php on line 148
[Fri Jul 29 05:21:25.986025 2016] [:error] [pid 2429] [client 14.139.122.50:53019] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/Google_Client/5f) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in:/var/sentora/temp/) in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Cache/File.php on line 149
[Fri Jul 29 05:21:25.986373 2016] [:error] [pid 2429] [client 14.139.122.50:53019] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Cache_Exception' with message 'Could not create storage directory: /tmp/Google_Client/5f' in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Cache/File.php:154\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Cache/File.php(139): Google_Cache_File->getCacheDir('ff3dffdeef0acdf...', true)\n#1 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Cache/File.php(134): Google_Cache_File->getCacheFile('ff3dffdeef0acdf...', true)\n#2 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Cache/File.php(95): Google_Cache_File->getWriteableCacheFile('ff3dffdeef0acdf...')\n#3 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(315): Google_Cache_File->set('ff3dffdeef0acdf...', '{"access_token"...')\n#4 /var/sentora/hostda in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/test2_ipleaders_in/process/google/google-api-php/src/Google/Cache/File.php on line 154
```

This is the error log I am receiving. I have checked for file permissions, and have kept it 777 in many places and especially in the tmp folder as mentioned in the error log. I desperately seek help on this, any insight is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one beautifully!

So as I was using Sentora, I searched for 'open_basedir Sentora' on Google, and found this: http://forums.sentora.org/showthread.php?tid=1674

I made a custom vhost entry:

- Admin > Module Admin (on Sentora CP).
- Apache Config (it's the very first option).
- Scrolled Down to the end of the page and under the Override a Virtual
  Host Setting I choose the website I wanted.
- Now on the text area input: Custom Entry I entered the following:

  php_admin_value open_basedir none

And now the Google Script is working fine! Thanks to @Unix-One's answer I was on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error message says, it appears that [php's open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) setting is preventing the script from reading the files from `/tmp` path. You probably want to check with your hosting provider if you are able to change that setting, or alternatively, change the temporary path in your application/library settings to the directory you have access to.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am on a self-managed hosting (Digital Ocean), I guess I will have to change this php's open_basedir setting myself, any insight on how can I do that?